# validating Large number of records

Tags: etl, data

What are the primary testing techniques/methods to validate the every data point in the rows of records on source side to Target. How do we handle when there are millions of records to be validated during both initial and incremental ETL process.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look for MapReduce techniques, in tools such as Hadoop.

MapReduce breaks sets of data for distributed computing (mapping) and summarizes (reducing) results in a distributed fashion as well, incrementally.

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm